# Is this sequence bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, optimization

Consider a sequence:
$$x_{k+1}=A(x_k)\cdot x_k$$
where $A(x_k)$ is a matrix and for a $d>0$
$$\|A(x_k)\|=\left\{\begin{aligned}<1,\;\|x_k\|>d\\=1,\;\|x_k\|=d\\>1,\;\|x_k\|<d\end{aligned}\right..$$

**Q:** Given $x_0\neq 0$, Is the sequence $\{x_k\}$ bounded? Does it converge?

Futhermore, if we replace $\|A(x_k)\|$ with $\rho(A(x_k))$ in the above condition, where $\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of $A$, does the same result hold?

---

*EDIT:* Intuitively, the sequence must be bounded, because whenever $\|x_k\|>d$, $\|x_{k+1}\|<\|x_k\|$ at next iteration. Thus finally $\|x_k\|$ may oscillate within an interval centered at $d$. Besides, if we use $\rho(A(x_k))$ other than $\|A(x_k)\|$, we cannot guarantee $\|x_{k+1}\|<\|x_k\|$ provided $\|x_k\|>d$, so the sequence may diverge. But I don't know how to formally prove these.

Comment: @AlexR. Well, I have tried several 2D cases, where I let $A(x_k)$ be different matrix $A_1$ and $A_2$ when $\|x_k\|>d$ and $\|x_k\|<d$, respectively. $\|A_1\|$ and $\|A_2\|$ satisfy above condition. The result showed that $\{x_k\}$ is bounded but not necessarily converges.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence doesn't necessarily converge. You can see this even in 1 dimension. Take $x_{0}=1$, and $d=1/2$ and let $A=1/4$ when $x_k<d$, $4$ when $x_k<d$ and 1 otherwise. Then the sequence becomes $1,1/4,1,1/4,...$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea about the boundedness? Or, more specifically, does there exist a $N$ such that for all $k>N$ we have $\|x_k\|<\bar{d}$ for a $\bar{d}>0$?